# Joins or group-by for aggregates - SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Forgive me if this question has been asked before - it's difficult to get down in words exactly what I want to do without an example.

I've got the following table

| County | Food |
| --- | --- |
| Bedfordshire | Pizza |
| Bedfordshire | Pasta |
| Bedfordshire | Potatoes |
| Bristol | Biscuits |
| Bristol | Pizza |
| Bristol | Panini |
| Buckinghamshire | Panini |

I'd like to grab the set of counties that contain the food "Pizza" and well as "Potatoes", and go on to do this for multiple pairwise combinations (and then 3 different types) of food across a large dataset. What's the most SQL-style efficient way to run this query - presumably joins are bad, groupbys and unions are good?

EDIT: The results could look something like, for example

| County | Pizza + Panini | Pizza + Potatoes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bedfordshire | 0 | 1 |
| Bristol | 0 | 0 |
| Buckinghamshire | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.  Your description is a bit vague.  What does "grab the set of countries" mean?

Comment: Editted. Country food pairs are unique, yes

Answer (score 0):

If you want pairs of foods with all countries that have them, then I would suggest a self join with aggregation:

```
select t1.food, t2.food, array_agg(t1.country)
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.country = t2.country and t1.food < t2.food
group by t1.food, t2.food;
```

The above formulation assumes that the `country`/`food` pairs are unique in the table.

Comment: just trying to understand 

what does array_agg do here? and why are we grouping by both foods?

and how would you deal with finding the 3 types of food case?

Comment: @ChristopherTurnbull . . . This produces pairs of foods with the list of countries (in an array).  This is much simpler than creating a separate column for every possible pair of products.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this might help. for the results see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5c70f511c075f086cb1fafc33c2606fe

since you are using snowflake you can use list_agg()

```
with content as (
select 
id,
group_concat(item," ") as food
from
table_acc
group by 1)


select
content.id,
sum(case when content.food like    '%iz%' 
         and  content.food  like  '%nin%'
         then 1 else  0 end)  as count_pizza_and_panini,
sum(case when content.food like    '%iz%' 
         and  content.food  like  '%tat%'
         then 1 else  0 end)  as count_pizza_and_potato
           
from content
group by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this on large datasets, you should avoid the self join, and execute the SQL using a single pass of the table:

```
WITH COUNTY_FOOD as (
SELECT CAST('Bedfordshire' AS VARCHAR(255)) AS "County", 
       CAST('Pizza' AS VARCHAR(255)) AS "Food" 
UNION ALL 
      SELECT CAST('Bedfordshire' AS VARCHAR(255)) AS "County", 
             CAST('Pasta' AS VARCHAR(255)) AS "Food"
UNION ALL 
      SELECT CAST('Bedfordshire' AS VARCHAR(255)) AS "County", 
             CAST('Potatoes' AS VARCHAR(255)) AS "Food"
UNION ALL 
      SELECT CAST('Bristol' AS VARCHAR(255)) AS "County", 
             CAST('Biscuits' AS VARCHAR(255)) AS "Food"
UNION ALL 
      SELECT CAST('Bristol' AS VARCHAR(255)) AS "County", 
             CAST('Pizza' AS VARCHAR(255)) AS "Food"
UNION ALL 
      SELECT CAST('Bristol' AS VARCHAR(255)) AS "County", 
             CAST('Panini' AS VARCHAR(255)) AS "Food"
UNION ALL 
      SELECT CAST('Buckinghamshire' AS VARCHAR(255)) AS "County", 
             CAST('Panini' AS VARCHAR(255)) AS "Food"
) 
--Apply Boolean Logic to pivoted columns
SELECT "County" AS "County", 
    iff("sum_Pizza">0 and "sum_Panini">0,1,0) AS "Pizza + Panini", 
    iff("sum_Pizza">0 and "sum_Potatoes">0,1,0) AS "Pizza + Potatoes" 
    FROM (
        --pivot out columns for each food type
         SELECT "County", SUM("Pizza") AS "sum_Pizza", SUM("Panini") AS "sum_Panini", SUM("Potatoes") AS "sum_Potatoes"
            FROM (
                    SELECT "County", 
                iff("Food"='Pizza',1,0) AS "Pizza", 
                iff("Food"='Panini',1,0) AS "Panini", 
                iff("Food"='Potatoes',1,0) AS "Potatoes"
                    FROM COUNTY_FOOD
                 )
         GROUP BY  "County"
         )
```